# Error inflating view on tab number 4

Tags: android, view, android-tabhost, tabwidget, android-inflate

There is a strange error in my code. I have a `TabHost` where I am adding a tab dynamically when a link of the `WebView`. I have tested this code on 4.4.2, it works fine. But on 2.3.3 and 2.3.6 and 2.1, it does not work.

I have customized the theme of the tab with a simple xml file.

All code since the tab number 4 that do not change theme look all white.

```
private void createTab(String url) {
    Log.i(TAG, "createTab");
    TabHost tabs = getTabHost();
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(tabs.getContext()).inflate(
            layouts[layoutTab], null);
    layoutTab = (layoutTab + 1) % 4;
    TabSpec spec = tabs.newTabSpec(Integer.toString(mTabs.getCounter()));
    spec.setContent(new MyTabContentFactory(url));
    spec.setIndicator(view);
    SingleTab st = new SingleTab(tabs.getCurrentTab(), url, spec);
    Log.i(DEBUG, st.toString());
    mTabs.getList().add(st);
    tabs.addTab(spec);      
    if (tabs.getTabWidget().getChildCount() < 2)
        tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    else
        tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    tabs.setCurrentTab(mTabs.getCounter());
    mTabs.incrementCounter();
}
```

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: No error, I setup that onbackpressed "delete" the current tab. In this case the tab number 4 looks fine

Comment: I solved in a strange way. I simply create a new xml file with another name and now all works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tab implementation in 2.x is buggy and I had difficulty refresing tab after removing a tab from tabhost. There is a fragment tab host implementation in support library which might suit the need.